# UNION 2 sql queries - wp_posts vs wp_terms - PHP, WORDPRESS

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pagination

I have a page where I'm displaying all taxonomy categories and all posts/pages. There I need to have ajax pagination so that my page won't load ages (or even not load). So I've built the pagination via sql query and now need to get both terms and posts with sql query, then union them so that my pagination will work properly and count including them all.

Here is my code:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM wp_term_taxonomy LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 
wp_terms.term_id) WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product-category'";

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE (post_type = 'products' OR post_type = 'page') 
AND (post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'suspended') AND ID NOT IN 
(231, 236, 1070, 1245) order by post_title ASC";

$sql = $sql1." UNION ".$sql2;

$query =  $sql . " limit " . $start . "," . $resultPerPage->perpage;
$list = $db_handle->runBackendQuery($query);
```

Above returns me following errors:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in .../dbcontroller.php on line 29

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in 
.../dbcontroller.php on line 38
```

I think I can join such 2 different things. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Too many tags here, mysql <> sql server. For a union to be successful the column list must match (which it most likely will not in this case).

Comment: Hmm...yes I agree with you. But not sure what to solve this @JacobH

Answer (score 1):

The error could happen because you have some error in your query for avoid this

You should select the same number of column and with corresponding data type so try avoiding select all  (*) and use explicit select column you should use a sintax  like eg:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT col_a1, col_a2, col_a3 FROM wp_term_taxonomy LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 
wp_terms.term_id) WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product-category'";

$sql2 = "SELECT col_b1, col_b2, col_b3 FROM wp_posts WHERE (post_type = 'products' OR post_type = 'page') 
AND (post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'suspended') AND ID NOT IN 
(231, 236, 1070, 1245) order by post_title ASC";

$sql = $sql1." UNION ".$sql2;

$query =  $sql . " limit " . $start . "," . $resultPerPage->perpage;
$list = $db_handle->runBackendQuery($query);
```

Comment: I just tried to select 4 columns for each of them and still same errors. Re data type - they can't be similiar as it is wp structure and I can't do anything there. Any other ideas? @scaisEdge

Comment: the data type must match   ... try also the query in IDE so you can see the real sql error